# C# Selenium - Simultaneous Browsers Interacting with each other

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

Need some suggestions here. I have an application I need to test using Selenium/SpecFlow/C#. The application is similar to skype. So I can text chat with people or I can phone them. So I am looking for:

User A - Login Chrome

User B - Login Firefox

User A calls User B or goes to text chat

User B Answers phone or texts back to user A

I am trying to figure out the best/easiest way to invoke a second browser instance and access the same browser functions and page objects.

Currently I have the below so I am using static calls. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
public class Browser
{
    static IWebDriver _driver;
    static WebDriverWait _wait;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's straight forward..you use different webdriver instance for corresponding browsers..If your web application is same in both browsers then of course you can use same browser functions and page objects provided that you use different webdriver instance respectively..